# POST карта и нерабочая материнка

Tags: железо, bios

Всем привет! Друзья подскажите, есть такая карточка (см. картинку), протестил на рабочих материнках, всё ОК.
Но есть две материнки на них индикатор показывает "00" при этом RST и IRDY не горят. А FRAME и CLR горят. 
Можно ли по этим признакам сделать какие-либо выводы.

БП заведомо рабочий.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Батарейку поменять попробуйте

Comment: Результат тот же.

Comment: А эта связка мать-проц-память хоть когда-то работала? Если нет - может проц несовместим?

Comment: Железа у меня много. Кроме матери всё заведомо рабочее. С подобными диагнозами у меня 2 метри лежат. А так всё протестировано на аналогах.

Comment: Может они несовместимы просто. Попробуйте младшую модель процессора туда воткнуть.

Comment: Пробовал и с разными процами и без проца.
Первая Мать GYGABYTE GA-8I945GZME-RH
Для теста процы были C2D e4300; C2D e2180; p4 631;
Вторая Мать ASUS P5GL